# Changing Windows file properties programmatically

Tags: windows, mp3

I have a lot of mp3 files in the following format...
`How to - Juno.mp3`

I then want everything before the **-** to be the "Title" property of the mp3 file and every thing after the **-** to be the "Album" property.

E.g. for file `How to - Juno.mp3`

Title = `How to`
Album = `Juno`

I am fed up of doing this by hand for many mp3 files.

Can this be done programmatically? e.g. I am a medium-level java coder and could this be done with a java program?

Basically, I am looking for a way to avoid doing this hardwork by hand and have a program do this for me....

Thanks,
Nandini

Comment: Hi - i am successfully  using CDDA extractor to rename my audio collection. It can rename in batch and be pimped to your hearts content regarding renaming audio files... > https://www.poikosoft.com/

Comment: There's a ton of tools out there that can do this for you already, no coding necessary, another is [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/)

Answer (score 0):

I use TagScanner for my mp3 needs

http://www.xdlab.ru/en/index.htm
or
https://tagscanner.en.softonic.com/

To create data from the filename go to the third tab (Tag Processor) and select the 'white page - arrow - box' icon, this generates data from the filename. Use the format `%title% - %album%` **select the files** and hit generate.

The first tab in the program does the opposite and renames the file based on the info. The second tab edits the ID3 information, just remember to hit save before changing file(s) selection after edits.